# Autocomplete Input text with JavaScript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to know how can I append $ sign at the start of input text field like $8.000

I am using the below javascript code for the same .

```
function autofild(input){
var num = input.value.replace(/\./g,'');
    if(!isNaN(num)){
        num = num.toString().split('').reverse().join('').replace(/(?=\d*\.?)(\d{3})/g,'$1.');
        num = num.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/^[\.]/,'');            
        input.value = num;
    }else{             
        input.value = input.value.replace(/[^\d\.]*/g,'');
    }        
}
```

HTML

```
<input id="vida_ingreso" onkeyup="autofild(this)" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
function autofild(input){
var num = input.value.substring(1, input.value.length);
num = num.replace(/\./g,'');
    if(!isNaN(num)){
        num = num.toString().split('').reverse().join('').replace(/(?=\d*\.?)(\d{3})/g,'$1.');
        num = num.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/^[\.]/,'');            
        input.value = '$' + num;
    }else{             
        input.value = '$' + input.value.replace(/[^\d\.]*/g,'');
    }        
}
```

Comment: The issue now is how to remove the format to manipulate the number...  ¿any suggestion?

Comment: @vyplow The second line does it: _input.value.substring(1, input.value.length)_